# why convert the SKSpriteNode when detect a collision in SpriteKit sometimes not working and throw an error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've build an game using swift. First I create a class named alienNode which inherited from SKSpriteNode

```
var hP = 0

init() {
    let alienTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Alien_Normal.png")
    self.hP = 5
    super.init(texture: alienTexture, color: UIColor.white, size: alienTexture.size())
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

then I create 3 aliens in GameScene

```
func buildAlien() {
    for i in 0...2 {
        let alienNode = AlienNode()
        addChild(alienNode)
        alienNode.name = kAlienName
        let position_i_Factor = i - 1
        alienNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2 + CGFloat(position_i_Factor * 130), y: size.height / 2 + 200)

        alienNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: alienNode.texture!, size: alienNode.size)
        alienNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        alienNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

        alienNode.physicsBody?.mass = 1000000


        alienNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.alien.rawValue
        alienNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.bullet.rawValue
    }
```

when I shoot a bullet, it detected collision pretty well, but when I convert
the SKSpriteNode to AlienNode, it works not good, sometimes it will throw an
error.

Here's the code in didBegin()

```
    let nodesName = [contact.bodyA.node?.name,contact.bodyB.node?.name]
    print(nodesName)

    if nodesName.contains(kAlienName) && nodesName.contains(kBulletName) {
        //A bullet hit a alien
        contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent() //remove the bullet
        print("hit")
        let alienNode = contact.bodyA.node as! AlienNode// it doesn't work sometimes
        alienNode.hP -= 1
        if alienNode.hP <= 0 {
            alienNode.removeFromParent()
            print("Alien killed")
        }
```

is that anything wrong with my code, how could I fix this. thank you really much!

Comment: Why do you think your `bodyA.node` must be an `AlienNode`?

Comment: Because I should store the hp value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what @OOPer is hinting at in his comment is:

How do you *know* that the `AlienNode` is `bodyA.node`?

Couldn't it just a well be `bodyB.node`?

You start out with this to fill your `nodesName` array

```
let nodesName = [contact.bodyA.node?.name,contact.bodyB.node?.name]
```

Next you check that `nodesName` actually contains `kAlienName` and `kBulletName`

```
if nodesName.contains(kAlienName) && nodesName.contains(kBulletName) {
```

But you still don't know the *order* of the nodes in your `nodesName` array.

Sometimes `bodyA.node` could be an `AlienNode` and other times it could be `bodyB.node`.

I imagine something like this could work:

```
if nodesName.contains(kAlienName) && nodesName.contains(kBulletName) {
    //find the alien node
    var alienNode: AlienNode?
    if let _ = contact.bodyA.node as? AlienNode {
        //it was a
        alienNode = contact.bodyA.node as? AlienNode
        contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent() //remove the bullet
    } else {
        //it was b
        alienNode = contact.bodyB.node as? AlienNode
        contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent() //remove the bullet
    }     
    print("hit")
    //it should be safe to force unwrap here
    alienNode!.hP -= 1
    if alienNode!.hP <= 0 {
        alienNode!.removeFromParent()
        print("Alien killed")
    }
```

It is untested but hopefully you get the idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I ask you another question? sometimes it detects double collision when crash one time, why?

Comment: @EthanChu Good question :) I'm afraid I can't really answer that question without knowing a bit more. I think you should post a new question with some code examples and explain what you are experiencing and what you are expecting. I'm sure someone can ask then.